# Rollup.js is not bundling my React Component Library fonts

Tags: reactjs, fonts, font-face, rollup, rollupjs

Everything works just fine when I view my React component library with Storybook. When I publish the library to the NPM registry, I install it into a dummy React app and everything works as expected except for the font. Below is my rollup.config.js plugins:

```
plugins: [
    external(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      babelHelpers: 'bundled',
    }),
    del({ targets: ['dist/*'] }),
    postcss(),
    url({
      include: ['**/*.woff'],
      limit: Infinity,
    }),
    copy({
      targets: [{ src: ['./src/fonts'], dest: 'dist' }],
    }),
],
```

Here is my font.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'CustomFontExample';
  src: local('CustomFontExample'),
    url('/fonts/CustomFontExample.woff')
      format('woff')
}
```

I believe the issue either lives within my Rollup.config.js or I'm not setting up my @font-face path correctly. I currently have it set to a relative path which works just fine when I view the components in Storybook.

Does anybody know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: You find the solution to this?

Comment: @jamesemanon, You find a solution? I started a Bounty.

Comment: no, I opted not to provide fonts.

Comment: @Bradley, Ton is using Rollup's URL plugin to handle the fonts, but here he is setting the limit to Infinity. This means the font will not be inlined and will be copied to the output directory. If the URL in the output CSS still references the original directory, that won't be accessible when the package is used in another project. Also, copy plugin moves the fonts to the dist directory, but again, if the URLs aren't updated, they'll point to the wrong place.